# How is the __name__ variable in a Python module defined?

Tags: python, python-module, python-internals

I'm aware of [the standard example](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts): if you execute a module directly then it's `__name__` global variable is defined as `"__main__"`. However, nowhere in the documentation can I find a precise description of how `__name__` is defined in the general case. The [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) says...

> Within a module, the module's name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable `__name__`.

...but what does it mean by "the module's name"? Is it just the name of the module (the filename with `.py` removed), or does it include the fully-qualified package name as well?

How is the value of the `__name__` variable in a Python module determined? For bonus points, indicate precisely where in the Python source code this operation is performed.

Comment: I've seen variations of this question out there, but I'm glad someone has brought the subject more depth.

Comment: Related post - [What does if __name__ == “__main__”: do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/465053)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is set to the absolute name of the module as imported. If you imported it as `foo.bar`, then `__name__` is set to `'foo.bar'`.

The name is determined in the [`import.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/import.c) module, but because that module handles various different types of imports (including zip imports, bytecode-only imports and extension modules) there are *several* code paths to trace through.

Normally, `import` statements are translated to a call to `__import__`, which is by default [implemented as a call to `PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/bltinmodule.c#l182). See the [`__import__()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) to get a feel for what the arguments mean. Within [`PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/import.c#l1228) relative names are resolved, so you can chase down the `name` variables there if you want to.

The rest of the module handles the actual imports, with `PyImport_AddModuleObject` creating the actual namespace object and setting the `name` key, but you can trace that `name` value back to `PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject`. By creating a module object, it's `__name__` value is set in the [`moduleobject.c` object constructor](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/moduleobject.c#l17).

Comment: Additionaly, the `as` subclause in `import` does not change the `__name__` attibute.

Answer (score 3):

The `__name__` variable is an attribute of the module that would be accessible by the name.

```
import os
assert os.__name__ == 'os'
```

Example self created module that scetches the import mechanism:

```
>>> import types
>>> m = types.ModuleType("name of module") # create new module with name
>>> exec "source_of_module = __name__" in m.__dict__ # execute source in module
>>> m.source_of_module
'name of module'
```

Lines from types module:

```
import sys
ModuleType = type(sys)
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `exec` is a function:  

    `exec("source_of_module = __name__", m.__dict__)`