# What does __name__ actually do in python?

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror

First of all I have to say, that I'm not new in Python. I know the *use* of `if __name__ == '__main__':` well enough. I just try to understand *how* the Python interpreter handles this. I wrote two scripts to test what's possible in Python. Note that that's actually really bad Python - I wouldn't make use of such things. I only want to learn about the *possibilities*.

main.py:

```
import bad.py


def main():

    print "Hello, World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

bad.py:

```
__name__ = '__main__' # I expected an Error caused by this line


def main():

    exit() # I know that this function shouldn't be used


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

There's no output by running `main.py` and I didn't really expect an output.

**what I want to know:**

- does `__name__ = '__main__'` in `bad.py` automatically change the variable `__name__` in `main.py`? Or can two *different* `'__main__'`-modules exist?
- is it possible to substitute an `import` statement just by manipulating `__name__`? If it is, how would you do that?
- when I change `exit()` to `print "Hello",`, The output is `"Hello"`, then an Error occurs:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
      import bad.py
  ImportError: No module named py
  ```

  could someone explain this behaviour?
- Are there any differences between python versions / operating systems? I tried this example in Python 2.7.6 on Linux2

**EDIT:**

Of course `import bad.py` doesn't work. `import`-statements don't want any file-endings. I did this mistake because I also program in C. I changed the line to `import bad`. The output looks like this now:

```
Hello Hello, World
```

Comment: Take a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883526/how-is-the-name-variable-in-a-python-module-defined . The answer is what you want. The `__name__` changes depending on how you might import a file in python.

Comment: @PrestonHager excuse me that I couldn't write _every_ point in the question's title - the answer of your linked question doesn't answer every point of my question. If these points are also duplicates, please leave a link to the other questions as well

Comment: Ok, the answer for if the `__name__` variable can be used for an import is no it can't. Python must call the `__import__()` function. The other question on system exit is interesting. There are no differences in these functions between Python 2 and 3, though I don't know for operating systems.

Comment: Have you searched the python documentation for references to `__name__`?

Comment: Here's a pretty decent explanation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Answer (score 0):

change your import statement to `import bad`

The `if __name__ == '__main__':` intention is to run this code if this program is run directly, as a main program. As you see you can overwrite the **name** value but the same effect would occur if you remove the if check in bad.

- `__name__` in bad.py is independent from `__name__` in main.py. You can see that when you again call main.py from another program.
- the import function is completely different from the `__name__` attribute. So no.
- you got the error because main continues with the next import after bad was finished. And it cannot import py.

Add some more print statements to follow the logic. You can also print `__name__` itself to see those values.

Comment: 1.) my import statement is already `import bad.py`. I don't know if you actually meant something else.

Comment: 2.) if I run `main.py`from another program again, it is completely new interpreted. Of course it is independent in this case, so this check doesn't make sense

Comment: 3.) As far as I know, the `import` keyword has influence to the value of `__name__` (in the imported script)

Comment: my fault. I meant `import bad`. remove the .py

Comment: Oh, of course ;) probably I programmed too much in C. I fixed it, now the output is `Hello Hello, World!` (without linebreak) as I expected

Comment: this also gives a good description: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: I read this question already and wouldn't have asked if it answered every of my question points