# How the __name__ of a Python module be defined with different import method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm struggling to understand how `__name__` of a module be defined, especially in different import methods. Suppose a directory tree:

```
├ main.py
└ test/
  ├── __init__.py
  ├── a
  │   ├── a1.py
  │   ├── base.py    <- a1.py and b1.py will import it
  │   └── __init__.py
  └── b
      ├── b1.py
      └── __init__.py
```

And here is `base.py`:

```py
# test/a/base.py
print("Base.py be imported, __name__ =", __name__)
```

`a1.py` imports `base.py` through relative import

```py
# test/a/a1.py
print("[a1.py] import base: start")
from . import base
print("[a1.py] import base: end")
```

then `a/__init__.py` imports `a1.py` and `base.py`

```py
# test/a/__init__.py
from . import base
from .a1 import *
```

For package `b`, the module `b1.py` import base through absolute import

```py
# test/b/b1.py
print("[b1.py] import base: start")
from test.a import base
print("[b1.py] import base: end")
```

and `b/__init__.py` import `b.py`

```py
# test/b/__init__.py
from test.b.b1 import *
```

Finally, the `test/__init__.py` will import both package `a` and `b` in different methods

```py
# method1
print(" ----- import a -----")
from .a import *
print(" ----- import b -----")
from .b import *

# method2
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/./")
print(" ----- import a -----")
from a import *
print(" ----- import b -----")
from b import *
```

If I import `test` in `main.py`, the output looks like it in method1

```
----- import a -----
Base.py be imported!, __name__ =  test.a.base
[a1.py] import base: start
[a1.py] import base: end
----- import b -----
[b1.py] import base: start
[b1.py] import base: end
```

The `__name__` of `base` is `test.a.base`. If I try it again in method2, the output looks like

```
----- import a -----
Base.py be imported!, __name__ =  a.base
[a1.py] import base: start
[a1.py] import base: end
----- import b -----
[b1.py] import base start
Base.py be imported!, __name__ =  test.a.base
[a1.py] import base: start
[a1.py] import base: end
[b1.py] import base: end
```

which is quite different to the method1.

How a module's `__name__` be defined? Does different import method, like absolute/relative import or different import seaching path, change the module's `__name__`? I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883526/how-is-the-name-variable-in-a-python-module-defined) but it still confuse me, and I want to know more about it under the hood. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your "other python script" below test/ folder?

Comment: @MaxPowers No, it's outside of `test`. I've edited the post for better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/./")`. Before you run this line, the path presumably contains the directory in which `main.py` lives. The only top-level package on that path is `test`. After, you have `a` and `b` available as well.

Python modules are named by path relative to package root. Before the path modification, you have the following packages available:

- `test`
- `test.a`
- `test.a.a1`
- `test.a.base`
- `test.b`
- `test.b.b1`

After the modification, you add the following additional modules:

- `a`
- `a.a1`
- `a.base`
- `b`
- `b.b1`

As far as python is concerned, these are entirely distinct modules coming from different packages, since the full names are different. If you inspect `sys.modules` before and after the modification, you will find that a new set of module objects with the new names has indeed been added.

Relative imports are resolved from the name of the module doing the import. So in `a.py`, you import `test.a.base` the first time and `a.base` the second time. However, the fully qualified imports starting with `test.` will always import from the first load.

The problem with this approach is that any modifications you make to say `a.a1` will not propagate to `test.a.a1`, which might be unexpected. That's one reason not to mess needlessly with the import path.

Two additional notes:

1. You have `/./` in your modified path. That's totally unnecessary. It means "current directory", which is meaningless after a file name, although the file manipulation routines seem to be able to handle it in this case. Had you done `/..` instead, there would have been no change because you would have added the parent directory of `test` again.
2. A similar behavior can be observed in scripts that live within packages. Python will load the script under its package name if it's imported in a dependency as well as under `__main__` when you first run it. This can lead to similar unexpected behavior, which is why it's not recommended to make library modules executable. You seem to have done a good job with that in how you placed `main.py`.